# Difference between specified and measured colours, matplotlib colormap

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

I'm having trouble replicating an old colormap I've used in matplotlib. It seems as if it was the default colormap because in the original code, no colormap was specified.

So looking at the old figure I made I've measured the colours from the `colorbar` using `gpick`. I've inputted these into a custom colormap as follows:

```
blue_red1 = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('mycmap', [
    (0,      '#6666de'),
    (0.1428, '#668cff'), 
    (0.2856, '#66d9ff'), 
    (0.4284, '#92ffce'), 
    (0.5712, '#d0ff90'), 
    (0.714,  '#ffe366'), 
    (0.8568, '#ff9b66'), 
    (1,      '#db6666')])

CS = plt.contourf(H, temps, diff_list, cmap=blue_red1)
plt.savefig('out.png')
```

Yet when I measure the output colours with `gpick` again they have different hex values (and I can tell they're different).

What could be causing this?

The original I'm trying to replicate, and the output from the custom colour map are linked below:

[image: original]

[image: replicate]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may get much closer to the desired result using the following. 
The logic is that each color in the colorbar is the value corresponding to the mean of its interval.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap

X,Y=np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0,1),np.linspace(0,1) )
Z = X+Y

blue_red1 = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('mycmap', [
    (0.0000, '#6666de'),
    (0.0625, '#6666de'),
    (0.1875, '#668cff'),
    (0.3125, '#66d9ff'), 
    (0.4375, '#92ffce'), 
    (0.5625, '#d0ff90'), 
    (0.6875, '#ffe366'), 
    (0.8125, '#ff9b66'), 
    (0.9375, '#db6666'), 
    (1.0000, '#db6666')])

CS = plt.contourf(X,Y,Z, cmap=blue_red1)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image]

The other option is to use a `ListedColormap`. This gives the accurate colors.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

X,Y=np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0,1),np.linspace(0,1) )
Z = X+Y

blue_red1 = ListedColormap(['#6666de','#668cff','#66d9ff','#92ffce','#d0ff90',
                            '#ffe366','#ff9b66','#db6666'],'mycmap')

CS = plt.contourf(X,Y,Z, cmap=blue_red1)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image]